# Error Compiling Report: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I have an error while compiling report the error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream
```

this is the code:

```
Map parameter = new HashMap();
parameter.put("customerId", notification_table.getValueAt(r, 0).toString());
ReportV sd = new ReportV();
sd.showReport(parameter);
```

this is the class I used:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;

public class ReportV {

    Connection conn = null;

    void showReport(Map parameters) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:pcn");
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("recipt.jrxml");
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conn);
            JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);
            viewer.setOpaque(true);
            viewer.setVisible(true);
            //make your JFrame visible
            this.add(viewer);
            this.setSize(300, 200);
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("CAUSE: " + ex.getCause());
            System.out.println("MESSAGE" + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("LOCAL MESSAGE" + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not imported the `ServletOutputStream` class.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
```

I believe that's part of Java EE, so you will need that lib in your classpath in addition to the standard java jdk.

Comment: Uncompilable source code - package javax.servlet does not exist

Comment: because it's not included in the standard jdk. you need Java EE for servlet stuff.

Comment: i have downloaded the library for this, but problem is not fixed

Comment: Are you using Maven? You may want to pull in the following package from maven central. GroupId: javax.servlet ArtifactId: servlet-api Version: 2.5 Type: jar Scope: compile

Comment: NetBeans is an IDE. Maven is a build management tool.  I'm guessing you are using Ant as your build management tool. In any case as others mentioned. You will need to use the J2EE libraries to get the ServletOutputStream class.